# where in talmud or halacha can one find about the separation of calling jews ashkenazi or sephardi?

Tags: talmud-gemara

where can one find the talmud text or halachah text or something similar that identifies or divides Jews as either Ashkenazim or Sephardim or Teymanim? (Also, is it two only, the first two only, because the last one, Yemenites or Teymanim, is sometimes left out)?

Comment: Separation between Ashkenazim and Sefardim happened around 1000 years after the collection of the Talmud.

Comment: source, please?

Comment: http://www.jewfaq.org/m/ashkseph.htm

Comment: Thank you for this link. From this link, it states "It's not clear when the split began". I need more clarity (when the split might have began) from those know might know.

Comment: The question asks about when the terms Askenazim and Sefardim first appeared. That is well after the talmud Bavli closed.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70953/ashkenazim-and-sephardim-for-example

Answer (score 1):

There was the Yeshiva in France, of the Tosafists, and there was a chain developing independently in Spain. These two schools had some differences in approach and in Minhag. After the Spanish expulsion, when many Spanish Jews moved East and carried the title Sfardy along with them, the divide became more pronounced.

Comment: source, please?

Comment: It is hard to point to any one place as my source. It is all over the place. But you can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephardic_law_and_customs or read about [the Rif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Alfasi)

Comment: This seems highly simplistic and completely ignores issues of their origins pre-Europe.

Comment: @doubleaa pre-Europe is pre-Ashkenaz and Sfard. What do you mean by simplistic? It is actually that simple. Different Poskim and therefore different Minhagim. See the introduction of the Darkei Moshe.

Comment: "pre-Europe is pre-Ashkenaz and Sfard" It before they got to those places, but it's not like the differences in tradition started then. The Rif was coming out of the Babylonian Gaonate whereas Rabbeinu Gershom may have been coming from Israeli Judaism or from a different Babylonian Yeshiva. Something like that at least. This answer is simplistic for not tracing the origins of their traditions with any detail other than to note they were sometimes different.

Comment: What makes you say there were differences then? Rabbeinu Gershon learned in Bavel and the Rabbonim in Ashkenaz followed the Psakim of the Gaonim whenever possible. Where do you see such differences between Rashi and the Ri Migash that are greater than the differences between Rashi and his grandchildren? Being separate, and developing separately, brings differences. They start small and get bigger.